# Are CSS data attributes available on mobile browsers?

Tags: css, mobile, custom-data-attribute

I have CSS that isn't working on any browsers on my smartphone (Galaxy S7 with Oreo). This is an example line of the code;

```
div[data-quickedit-field-id="node/859/body/en/full"] th{background-color: #81CFD6;}
```

Here's some background; this site has other code that works on my phone, this code works on desktop, I've checked the W3C Schools website and the Mozilla Developer website (as well as a few others) and I haven't been able to find any information on this, so I'm wondering if there's any reason the data attributes wouldn't work on smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

Only use quickedit for users that have access to in-place editing else when a testbot checks as an anonymous user it generates an error. Try to avoid the code unless it is necessary.

Comment: That data attribute is added by Drupal. I have no control over that. The reason I use it is because it's one of the only things that Drupal generates that I can target in CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have any prefixes so you have to change the way it interacts. I don't have experience with drupal.  So sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute selectors [should work](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20selectors) in all the modern mobile browsers. Checked that with your attribute and value and it is working good in my mobile (I've checked in Motorolla One Power and Redmi Note 7 Pro using chrome browser).

Here is the link to check in mobile: http://naasu.me/su-fixes/css/are-css-data-attributes-available-on-mobile-browsers/

If this is still not working for you, try using contains selector by adding `*` with the attribute(`[attribute*=value]`).

Comment: The asterisks don't seem to be working either. I thought this would be fine too, but it's just not working.